# queue.yaml not deployed when i use mvn appengine:deploy

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I updated my `pom.xml` to use the new mvn appengine plugin

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <project>{project_id}</project>
                <devserver.host>0.0.0.0</devserver.host>
                <devserver.port>1984</devserver.port>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Now when I run `mvn appengine:deploy` it converts my `queue.xml` to `queue.yaml` in the staging directory. However this queue configuration is not deployed.

I have tried so many ways to deploy it to google cloud but nothing worked. This setup is for my cloud endpoints project setup. The documentations do not cover this.

This is the maven plugin code i added after trying your suggestion out .

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <project>{project_id}</project>
            <devserver.host>0.0.0.0</devserver.host>
            <devserver.port>1984</devserver.port>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: It seems that 1.2.0 is throwing the `Directories are not supported` error. Can you try using version 1.0.0?

Comment: Give me a minute let me give it a shot

Comment: It worked with 1.0.0 , wow im surprised how that happened , Thanks @DevilingMaster why is it now working for 1.2.0? Are they planning to scrap it moving forward ?.

Comment: It seems that the `This is the maven plugin code i added after trying your suggestion out` is the same as the previous. Maybe a copy-paste error?

Comment: I open an issue related to the plugin version: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin/issues/144

Comment: @DevilingMaster i appreciate it .

Answer (score 0):

I opened a [similar issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin/issues/143) on the project board

By default, only the `app.yaml` file is deployed (which represents the application).
If you want (in addition, or only) the queue.yaml, or even the cron or index, you need to specify those files inside the plugin configuration.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${appengine.maven.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <deployables>
            <param>target/appengine-staging/app.yaml</param>
            <param>target/appengine-staging/cron.yaml</param>
            <param>target/appengine-staging/queue.yaml</param>
            <param>target/appengine-staging/index.yaml</param>
        </deployables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Please remember that if you specificy certain files, the `app.yaml` files should be added as well. It is deployed by default only if the `deployabels` parameter is missing.

Playing with this parameter you can choose which files to deploy

Comment: Even when i do this it doesnt work it says directories are not required .

Comment: This is what i get [INFO] GCLOUD: WARNING: The "module" parameter in application .yaml files is deprecated. Please use the "service" parameter instead.
[INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: Directories are not supported [P:\RareAtom\Tita\tita-backend\target\appengine-staging].  You must provide explicit yaml files.
[INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Errors occurred while parsing the App Engine app configuration.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Please note mine is a cloud endpoints project that might not support this , Please check this link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/using-maven it points out that it might not be supported .

Comment: About the "module" error, you have to declare in the `appengine-web.xml` the node `<service></service>`, because `<module></module>` is not to be used anymore.
It seems that you have configured a folder (this is why is getting thos) and not specific yaml files. Can you post your Maven plugin configuration?

Comment: Posted it , The comment wouldn't take the amount of characters or code block

Comment: Please edit your main post when additional data is required, avoid to create other answers.
Can you post, from the Maven logs, the full command that is called from the deploy procedure?